# Add role in ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: roles, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

How can I add roles for user menu management in ASP.NET Core 6 Identity?

There is table for ASP.NET roles and other. How can I use this?

I can't find any complete and effective documentation on this issue.

Adding Login and register to role for menu access

Comment: From your description, I think you can create a form to show all the roles in database, Then when you select a role, It will assign this role to the currently logged in user. You can use `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, defaultrole.Name)` to achieve it.

Answer (score -2):

Let me suggest working through Microsoft's excellent Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio